How to determine whether code is running in a JS VM such as Remix, as opposed to ETH mainnet?
block.chainid always returns 1 for both Remix VM and ETH mainnet. There has to be some intrinsic variable that will always return a different value compared to the other environment.
I'm aware I could infer this by interface-calling a method of some external mainnet contract that I know exists and seeing if it throws, but I would prefer a simpler way than that.

One way is to check block.number. In the Remix VM environment, it will increment rapidly with each transaction or block mined. However, on the ETH mainnet or testnet, it will progress much more slowly, corresponding to the actual block production rate on the Ethereum network. Therefore, by checking the rate of increase of block.number, you can infer whether your code is running in the Remix VM or on the mainnet/testnet.
Additionally, in the Remix VM environment, block.number always gets reinitialised when you refresh the browser and reconnect to Remix VM, starting with a very low value (i.e., usually <10 after contract deployment). In contrast, on the Ethereum mainnet or testnet, it's a significantly higher value (i.e., in the millions) and always keeps incrementing irrespective of your transactions, as transactions are continually happening on the network.
